# C# can't read and interpret web API/JSON

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

My first question here, probably because I found loads of previous questions & answers here :) I'm just a hobby programmer, I know only the basics, but I just love programming :D
I've been cracking my head over the following problem for 2 days now, and I wonder if you guys could help me?

I'm programming a GUI monitor for my bitcoin/altcoin miners (specifically, ccminer for NVIDIA miners), and I want a miner to be able to jump on the most profitable coin if I have set a config for it.
The easiest way to get these numbers would be trough the numerous web API's, like [this](http://www.coinmine.pw/api.php?method=coinprofit) and [this](http://www.whattomine.com/coins.json). So you can see, there are numerous API's (would've linked more, but not allowed yet), but none of them seems to work.

This is the code I have so far:

```
class Api
{
    public static List<Coins> _download_serialized_json_data(string address)
    {
        List<Coins> coinList = new List<Coins>();
        using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
        {
            string jsonData = web.DownloadString(address);
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonData);


            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Coins c = new Coins();
                c.tag = json["coins"][i]["tag"];

                coinList.Add(c);
            }
        }

        return coinList;
    }
}

public class Coins
{
    public string tag { get; set; }
}
```

ATM, I'm using the debug mode just to look at what's inside the objects but when I try to use my method at this api (or any other with corresponding elements) but at

```
c.tag = json["coins"][i]["tag"];
```

It errors out. I don't know where to find the exact error too, but even when I'm trying JArray.Parse it just doesn't work. Am I making a crucial mistake somewhere?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
Webclient wc = new Webclient();
var json = wc.DownloadString("http://www.whattomine.com/coins.json"); //your 2nd link
var coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Coins>(json);
```

---

```
public class Coins
{
    public Dictionary<string, Coin> coins = null;
}
public class Coin
{
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string algorithm { get; set; }
    public double block_reward { get; set; }
    public int block_time { get; set; }
    public int last_block { get; set; }
    public double difficulty { get; set; }
    public double difficulty24 { get; set; }
    public double nethash { get; set; }
    public double exchange_rate { get; set; }
    public string market_cap { get; set; }
    public double volume { get; set; }
    public int profitability { get; set; }
    public int profitability24 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was actually looking for at first. But when I tried to set-up the classes, I didn't know about the usage of Dictionary here, so I ended up with a class for each different coin ^^' But that wasn't dynamic, so I tried that.
This actually helped me out a lot! Thx :D

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 c.tag = json["coins"][i]["tag"].ToString();
```

Comment: No, that didn't work ;) But the answer by L.B. solved it for me! Thanks for trying :D